# How do you symbolize "the x" when x has a condition

Tags: logic

Let me explain. Suppose I have a question that asks me to symbolize "the smallest car has no air conditioning" from the domain of vehicles. I am thinking like this:

"1.If x is a car AND

2.there does not exist another vehicle y such that vehicle y is car and vehicle x is larger than y AND

3.for all a(IF a is a car and there does not exist another vehicle b such that b is a car and a is larger than B, then x=a) AND

4. it is not the case that x has an air conditioner"

Those four lines are how I symbolized it. But, I am apparently wrong. At first, I wanted to change it to and if then (if 1,2 & 3 then 4) but that I don't think that is correct because that opens up the possibility that such a car does not exist which goes against the question.

Then I considered changing line 2 and 3's there exists to "for all vehicles y, if they are car then they are larger than x). That didn't work too.

And with that, I fear I have come to my wits end. I don't know if the issue is my interpretation or my symbolization and that is leaving me clueless as to what to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want 1 to be a conditional, because you are asserting that at least one car exists. With 2, you need to be explicit that a car y is not identical with x, otherwise you would be saying that x is smaller than itself. Also, 3 is redundant: you seem to be going for an expression along the lines of Russell's theory of definite descriptions, but it is not needed here, because there is only one smallest car. You want something like the following:

1. There exists an x that is a car; AND
2. For any y, if y is a car and y is not identical with x then x is smaller than y; AND
3. It is not the case that x has an air conditioner.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I thought Russel's definition was meant to be used in any case where you want to specify the A is B. Why is that not the case here. Why is this particular question different from saying something like the Car in the park has no air conditioning.

Comment: Unless there are infinitely many cars, there has to be a smallest one. So we do not need to specify that it is unique. A car in a car park is not guaranteed to be unique unless we say it is so.

Comment: Can’t there be two smallest cars of exactly identical size? Both the Steelers and the Patriots are the team with the most Super Bowl wins.

Comment: @Bumble Oh, that makes sense. Since it was already specified, no need to declare it to be unique. Thank you